# First two moments of $\sin(X_1)/\sin(X_2)$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, variance

Let $X_1\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$ and $X_2\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2)$ be two **independent** random variables.

The task is to compute
\begin{equation}
E\left[\frac{\sin(X_1)}{\sin(X_2)}\right] = \;?
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
E\left[\left(\frac{\sin(X_1)}{\sin(X_2)}\right)^2\right] = \;?
\end{equation}

Comment: Not integrable: the expectation does not exist.

Comment: $X_2$ can be written as $X_2=\mu_2+Y_2$, where $Y_2\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_2)$. Would the following assumption $\mu_2\neq k\pi$, $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$ help in any way?

Comment: I don't think so.  Near $0$ you have $\sin x_2\approx 1/x_2$, integrated against the normal density near $0$.  The density there might be numerically small, but its positive there and the non-integrability of $1/x$ is decisive.